# Is it possible to limit the projects which specflow searches for tests when generating Step bindings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, specflow

My new workplace has a very large C# solution in Visual Studio 2017 with over 100 projects, of which only one is directly relevant to my job (web acceptance tests via specflow & selenium).

We have intermittent problems with CPU usage & tests not being found in the test explorer, occurring whenever Specflow decides it needs to search for and regenerate test bindings - as it takes some hours to complete, during which Visual Studio is not useful.

From experimentation, I know that if I open only the one project relevant to my work, then specflow finds all the tests in seconds and is immediately useable.

But sadly we need the whole solution to be loaded at least when building new code to be tested.

Is there a way to limit which projects (or paths) Specflow and/or test explorer is searching in for tests, & subsequently generating step bindings from?

I’m hoping for a local settings file (references to .runsettings), but haven’t been able to find any instructions for how to configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such an option available.

This looks to me we have to improve the VS Extension too handle that many projects.
Could you please open an issue here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow

There we can discuss, what we can do, to make SpecFlow for you usable.

Comment: See related issue on the Specflow github https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1261